# MacOS - Linking to Python.framework - setting path in script

Tags: python, objective-c, xcode, macos

In my Mac OS app, I am including my own Python 2.7 Framework.

I don't know how best to code the path so that my framework is used (not the one from */Library/Frameworks*):

- Hard code it in the Python script by getting working directory, etc
- Do it in my Obj-C class by getting *DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH*, appending script name, and then passing the path as an argument to *NSTask*

What's the advantage of one vs another?

Comment: I've done something like this before and I chose to make the bundle's main executable a *script*.  That script can then set library path variables correctly (based on its location) and invoke a *second* executable at the end.